# Shell / Sh Script on a MacBook - How to filter an output in a shell script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, sh

I try to filter the output of the shell command
`pmset -g batt`. It shows information about the battery status in MacOS. The output is for me

`Now drawing from 'AC Power'
 -InternalBattery-0 (id=XXXXXXX)    87%; charging; (no estimate) present: true`

and I just want to have `87%` as a variable and a variable if it´s charging or not like charging = 1 or 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bash, you could do:

```
read percent charg <<< $( pmset -g batt | awk 'NR<3{printf "%s ", $NF }' RS=\; )
```

to assign variables `percent` and `charg`.  This will assing the string "charging" to the latter as opposed to an integer value.

If you're not using a shell that accepts the herestring syntax, you can do:

```
read percent charg << EOF
$( pmset -g batt | awk 'NR<3{printf "%s ", $NF}' RS=\; )
EOF
```

Comment: My output is `awk: weird printf conversion % 
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
awk: not enough args in printf(100% )
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1`

Comment: Now with 99% the output is `awk: weird printf conversion % 
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
awk: not enough args in printf(99% )
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1`

Comment: And when I try to echo $percent is the output nothing.

Comment: @I. Schuhmacher.  My apologies.  I have edited the solution, and it should work for you.